# How do I find the Jacobi matrix?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inner-products

I've never done questions like these, so I would very much like some help.

We are given a function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=\langle x,\xi\rangle^2$ where $\langle\,,\rangle$ is the standard inner product of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\xi \in \mathbb R^n$.

Find $D_f(a)$, meaning, the differential of $f$ in point $a$, or in other words, the jacobi matrix multiplied by vector $a$.

Thanks, I would very much like an explanation on how to approach this

Comment: I realize full well that because the function goes to $\mathbb R^1$ then the Jacobi matrix is just the gradient vector. But generally speaking, if I wanted to find the jacobi matrix of a function, how would I do it?

Comment: Try $n=2,$ let your $x$ refer to the vector with variable entries $(x,y),$ let $\xi = (a,b)$ with constant entries, and actually write out your $f.$ Just write it out and find the gradient. Just do it.

Comment: In that case, $D_f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} 2a^2x+2aby \\ 2abx+2b^2y \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you. If you do $n=3$ with $(x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c)$ I think you will have the pattern, which is pretty concrete in this case. Note that your first entry is $2a$ times $ax+by,$ while your second entry is $2b$ times the same thing.

Comment: I think I have an idea as well. it is possible to say that incase of general $n$: $f(x)=(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \xi_i)^2$. and so, $\frac{df}{dx_j} = 2(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \xi_i)+\xi_j$

Comment: If you switch the final $+$ sign you typed to a multiplication sign, yes.

Comment: yeah right, ofcourse it is multiplication. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Would like someone to review this answer.

let's say $x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\x_2\\ \vdots \\x_n\end{pmatrix}$ and $\xi =\begin{pmatrix} \xi_1 \\\xi_2\\ \vdots \\\xi_n\end{pmatrix}$

then $f(x)=<x,\xi>^2 = (x_1\xi_1+x_2\xi_2+...+x_n\xi_n)^2$

now, instead of actually computing$(x_1\xi_1+x_2\xi_2+...+x_n\xi_n)^2$, we can derive it as such. We can say that the derivative with respect to the variable $x_j$ is: $\frac{d f}{d x_j} = 2\xi_j(x_1\xi_1+x_2\xi_2+...+x_n\xi_n)$